# Error in multiple regression prediction interval

Tags: r

This is the error message:

> Error in qt((1 - level)/2, df) : Non-numeric argument to mathematical function

What I am trying to do is to fit a model to check the association between SBP and age with sex and race adjustments.
My code uses the `uwIntroStats` package: the code to fit the model works. Sex (`male`) is coded as 0 for female and 1 for male, `race` is coded 1 to 4.

```
library(uwIntroStats)
data(mri)
model <- regress("mean", sbp~age*male+as.factor(race), data = mri)
predict(model, data.frame(age=70,male=0,race=2),interval="prediction")
```

Any reasons why the error occurs and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Please share a portion of your data. Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to make a reproducible example if you're unsure

Comment: @astrofunkswag, `library(uwIntroStats); data(mri)` will make this reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to name the `newdata` argument: otherwise the `predict` method thinks you're trying to specify the next unmatched argument, which is `level`. From `?predict.uRegress`:

> ## S3 method for class 'uRegress' 
>      predict(object,interval="prediction",level=0.95, ...)

So

```
predict(model, newdata=data.frame(age=70,male=0,race=2),
        interval="prediction")
```

works (you don't actually need to specify `interval="prediction"` - that's the default value).